# Enumerating 100,000+ folder hierarchy taking hours

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Why is this code taking hours to complete :

```
public void SetRoot(string path)
{
    Tag = path;
    BeginUpdate();
    AddFolderRecursive(Nodes, path);
    EndUpdate();
}

private void AddFolderRecursive(TreeNodeCollection nodes, string path)
{
    try
    {
        var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).OrderBy(d => d).Select(d => d.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last());
        TreeNode node;
        ShellFileGetInfo.FolderIcons fi;
        foreach (var d in dirs)
        {
            node = nodes.Add(Path.Combine(path, d), d, ImageList.Images.Count);
            node.Tag = Path.Combine(path, d);
            node.SelectedImageIndex = ImageList.Images.Count + 1;
            fi = ShellFileGetInfo.GetFolderIcon((string)node.Tag, false);
//                  ImageList.Images.Add(fi.closed);
//                  ImageList.Images.Add(fi.open);
            AddFolderRecursive(node.Nodes, (string)node.Tag);
        }
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {

    }
}
```

I have left this code running for 14 hours now and it still has not completed getting a list of all the folders when passing calling it like `SetRoot( @"c:\" );`.  The code is working, it is adding to the tree, but this is just ridiculous.

[image: 124,157 folders]

Essentially, I want to popular the treeview with all folders on my drive (so the treeview is searchable) AND use the actual folder icons (which I am using `SHGetFileInfo` p/invoke with the requisite params to do so).  Even without getting the icon (which there is another problem I am having is that getting the icon of the folder is unique on a folder by folder basis even though the icon images themselves may be the same. I can not see a way to determine - quickly - if I already have that image saved in my TreeView's `ImageList` - aka, the folder icon for 'c:\windows' is the same as 'c:\windows\system32', however the handle, etc all return different information so there doesn't seem to be anything to go on to uniquely index them.).

What can be adjusted in my code to make this process much faster, while still retaining the folder icons from the system ? Keep in mind, that I also want ALL folders without skipping empty ones as

(I can't even show a picture of the TreeView as I stopped the loop from running after 14 hours before it finished displaying).

To test the speed of the TreeView control, I wrote the following code :

```
DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;
treeView1.BeginUpdate();
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    int x = 0;
    while (x < 100000)
    {
        x++;
        if (treeView1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            treeView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { treeView1.Nodes.Add("Node - " + x); } );
        }
    }
});
treeView1.EndUpdate();
Text = start.ToLongTimeString() + " - " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString();
```

And here is a screenshot of the results :

[image: 100,000 items in TreeView]

As you can see, to populate the TreeView with 100,000 items happens *very* quickly at approximately 2 minutes provided you use `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` to prevent the control from drawing or refreshing on every item.  This also shows that it is definitely not the TreeView control which is holding me back -- 14 hours is excessive - even with a drive from 1996, 14 hours to enumerate 100,000 folders, is way too long.

Comment: You have a treeview with 800k nodes and an image list with 800k images. Yes, it's undoubtedly "slow". Make it virtual, keep in memory only expanded nodes!!! Do not even scan entire HD in one shot!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - it's actually just the folders, so 100k nodes.  I can add 100k nodes to a treeview pretty quick with just linq and a bit of random-ness to disperse the nodes.   Even in a ListView, i loaded 200k items in under 1 second.   I considered that, however need to be able to search the tree -- and to do that, the nodes MUST be present first.

Comment: First if all you're pushing treeview at its limits, second you have **images** you obtain from each folder. Try to do everything when a node is expanded, really you will make a favor to your users. About searching...well a tree isn't really best structure for a free text search and treeview nodes aren't designed for a fast search

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - yes, I understand that.  Presently, no one offers a search option on the contents of a TreeView.   Windows 10 search is attrocious -- simply loading my 'Downloads' folder in 'explorer.exe' can take several minutes -- to display 110 files -.- .  I am looking to work around this.  Regarding duplicity of icons, what do you suggest there since I am given nothing to check against.

Comment: Indexed folders  _should_ search fast, not indexed...well. AFAIK There isn't much you can do for icons, just load (and dispose) them **when required**.

Comment: It sure would be nice to see what SHGetFileInfo is looking at to determine the icon required to load, overlays, etc.  It's ok to add new icons to the index, but I would really prefer to leave the generics loaded only once. The problem is, I need a quick way to check if x unique icon already loaded (by tag in imagelist) is the same as y icon not loaded - before I `.Clone()` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further research I found that the issue is that the methods available for enumerating files and folders is very slow, and that when a folder is not accessible an `UnauthorizedAccessException` is thrown which has an inherant delay of around 200ms per incident. These exceptions stack and cause a large delay.

Additionally, Davids statement with regards to a quadratic exponent in adding items to the TreeView causes further delay is also true, however in this case, the additional delay is disproportionate to the scaling of TreeView node addition only.

To solve this problem, I was able to narrow it down to 3 issues, two of which I have completely solved so those portions of the control function within a reasonable time-frame. Breaking it down, here are the 3 issues causing delay with the OP question:

- TreeView node addition is exponentially slow the deeper the tree, and the more nodes are added.
- File system access does not access the native Journaling system available for NTFS and thus each file or directory is individually sourced per call. Further, if a folder is marked as restricted, the `UnauthorizedAccessException` imposes an artificial delay of approximately 200ms per encounter.
- Retrieval of custom folder icons requests several IO actions (with their respective delays), and further the method above for storing every icon pair is inefficient, causing it's own additional delays even though minor in this scope, the delay is also relevant.

After narrowing the scope of the delay, I was able to target these factors to reduce them one by one.

---

### Speeding up getting a list of folders

The first thing I had to do, was replace the file system access method with something more viable - direct access to the NTFS Journal system which I was able to do by harvesting some code from [StCroixSkipper's USN Journal Explorer v1.3](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/1017/entry-2587-stcroixskippers-usn-journal-explorer-v13/) and [MFT Scanner in VB.NET](http://mftscanner.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) to make the following class [NtfsUsnJournal.cs](http://pastebin.com/WpJU60W2) which I put on pastebin as this exceeds what I can post on StackOverflow.

*This change allowed me to retrieve all folders recursively on the C drive, in under 4 seconds*

NOTE: I have thus-far been unable to figure out a way to access the Journal without requiring the elevated (Administrator) privilege for the application. All attempts to access the Journal without elevation resulted in denied access exceptions.

---

### Improving TreeView performance for large sets of nested Nodes

Next, I needed to improve the TreeView's performance to be able to add over 100,000 nested nodes as the current folder structure loaded. To do this, took a bit of Google-fu, and some tinkering to adjust the code to function for the above class's Usn format.

The result is the following addition to a customer usercontrol extending TreeView :

```
#region TreeViewFast
private readonly Dictionary<ulong, TreeNode> _treeNodes = new Dictionary<ulong, TreeNode>();

/// <summary>
/// Load the TreeView with items.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Item type</typeparam>
/// <param name="items">Collection of items</param>
/// <param name="getId">Function to parse Id value from item object</param>
/// <param name="getParentId">Function to parse parentId value from item object</param>
/// <param name="getDisplayName">Function to parse display name value from item object. This is used as node text.</param>
public void LoadItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, ulong> getId, Func<T, ulong?> getParentId, Func<T, string> getDisplayName)
{
    // Clear view and internal dictionary
    Nodes.Clear();
    _treeNodes.Clear();

    // Load internal dictionary with nodes
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var id = getId(item);
        var displayName = getDisplayName(item);
        var node = new TreeNode { Name = id.ToString(), Text = displayName, Tag = item };
        _treeNodes.Add(getId(item), node);
    }

    // Create hierarchy and load into view
    foreach (var id in _treeNodes.Keys)
    {
        var node = GetNode(id);
        var obj = (T)node.Tag;
        var parentId = getParentId(obj);

        if (parentId.HasValue)
        {
            var parentNode = GetNode(parentId.Value);
            if(parentNode == null)
            {
                Nodes.Add(node);
            } else
            {
                parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Nodes.Add(node);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Get a handle to the object collection.
/// This is convenient if you want to search the object collection.
/// </summary>
public IQueryable<T> GetItems<T>()
{
    return _treeNodes.Values.Select(x => (T)x.Tag).AsQueryable();
}

/// <summary>
/// Retrieve TreeNode by Id.
/// Useful when you want to select a specific node.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">Item id</param>
public TreeNode GetNode(ulong id)
{
    try
    {
        return _treeNodes[id];
    } catch (KeyNotFoundException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Retrieve item object by Id.
/// Useful when you want to get hold of object for reading or further manipulating.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Item type</typeparam>
/// <param name="id">Item id</param>
/// <returns>Item object</returns>
public T GetItem<T>(ulong id)
{
    return (T)GetNode(id).Tag;
}


/// <summary>
/// Get parent item.
/// Will return NULL if item is at top level.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Item type</typeparam>
/// <param name="id">Item id</param>
/// <returns>Item object</returns>
public T GetParent<T>(ulong id) where T : class
{
    var parentNode = GetNode(id).Parent;
    return parentNode == null ? null : (T)Parent.Tag;
}

/// <summary>
/// Retrieve descendants to specified item.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Item type</typeparam>
/// <param name="id">Item id</param>
/// <param name="deepLimit">Number of generations to traverse down. 1 means only direct children. Null means no limit.</param>
/// <returns>List of item objects</returns>
public List<T> GetDescendants<T>(ulong id, int? deepLimit = null)
{
    var node = GetNode(id);
    var enumerator = node.Nodes.GetEnumerator();
    var items = new List<T>();

    if (deepLimit.HasValue && deepLimit.Value <= 0)
        return items;

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // Add child
        var childNode = (TreeNode)enumerator.Current;
        var childItem = (T)childNode.Tag;
        items.Add(childItem);

        // If requested add grandchildren recursively
        var childDeepLimit = deepLimit.HasValue ? deepLimit.Value - 1 : (int?)null;
        if (!deepLimit.HasValue || childDeepLimit > 0)
        {
            var childId = ulong.Parse(childNode.Name);
            var descendants = GetDescendants<T>(childId, childDeepLimit);
            items.AddRange(descendants);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
#endregion
```

To use, I created a new method which acts as a simple 'loader' as follows :

```
public void PopulateTree(string path)
{
    Tag = path;
    using (NtfsUsnJournal ntfs = new NtfsUsnJournal(new DriveInfo(path)))
    {
        List<NtfsUsnJournal.UsnEntry> folders;
        ntfs.GetNtfsVolumeFolders(out folders);


        Func<NtfsUsnJournal.UsnEntry, ulong> getId = (x => x.FileReferenceNumber);
        Func<NtfsUsnJournal.UsnEntry, ulong?> getParentId = (x => x.ParentFileReferenceNumber);
        Func<NtfsUsnJournal.UsnEntry, string> getDisplayName = (x => x.Name);

        LoadItems(folders, getId, getParentId, getDisplayName);
    }
}
```

*Testing this, it now only takes 6 seconds to fully load all 100,000+ folders into the TreeView, and user experience is instant expanding*

---

### Folders with custom icons

This is the last place which I am currently hung up on, and am still searching for a way to fully improve this.

What I have done so far, is to do a check to see if `desktop.ini` exists within the folder, and if it does, *then* call the `SHGetFileInfo` pinvoke to get the custom folder icon. I then add the folder that was being expanded to an internal list signaling that I already checked that folder and got any associated icons, which all happens inside the `OnBeforeExpand` event. While these calls are inexpensive, it still adds a significant delay (expanding c:\windows takes 12 seconds) to the process.

Here is the code for that (also inside the custom TreeView)

```
private List<string> _expandedCache;

protected override void OnBeforeExpand(TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_expandedCache.Contains(e.Node.FullPath))
    {
        BeginUpdate();
        ShellFileGetInfo.FolderIcons fi;
        _expandedCache.Add(e.Node.FullPath);
        string curPath;
        foreach(TreeNode n in e.Node.Nodes)
        {
            curPath = Path.Combine((string)Tag, n.FullPath.Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));
            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(curPath, "desktop.ini")) == true)
            {
                fi = ShellFileGetInfo.GetFolderIcon(curPath, false);
                if(fi.closed != null || fi.open != null)
                {
                    ImageList.Images.Add(fi.closed);
                    ImageList.Images.Add(fi.open);
                    n.SelectedImageIndex = ImageList.Images.Count - 1;
                    n.ImageIndex = ImageList.Images.Count - 2;
                }
            }
        }
        EndUpdate();
    }
    base.OnBeforeExpand(e);
}
```

*This is the last major set-back which I believe there is a way to access much faster than the conventional `File.Exists()` method and `SHGetFileInfo` pinvoke for obtaining custom folder icons in an inexpensive manner*

**Update**: After more testing, I was able to narrow down this last problem to when adding an Icon to the ImageList.  Each Time an image is added to an ImageList that is connected to the TreeView, the entire TreeView of nodes is refreshed. If anyone has an idea on how to make all of this work together while keeping the performance high at this magnitude of images, please let me know. Or if this internal refresh could somehow be pushed to the background in a way that doesn't lock the UI.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows tree view control is simply not designed to hold so many nodes. It is simply impossible for you to populate this control with thousands of nodes in realistic time. Furthermore it is surely unrealistic to even enumerate all of those items in short time. Even more awkward is attempting to extract icons for every object in the tree ahead of time.

The way forward is that you do not attempt to populate the control with all items. Just populate parent nodes. Then when they are opened enumerate and add the children. This is how all shell programs operate.

Comment: approx 2 minutes to add 100,000 items in a loop to the treeview control root.    Clearly, the TreeView is not the reason why this is 14 hours (and counting) slow. posting test info now on question so you can see the treeview isn't the slow part

Comment: David - please see the appended information and test case showing that - not only is it possible to "hold so many nodes" it is also viable "in realistic time".  The TreeView control, is not why this is taking 14+ hours to enumerate through 100,000 folders -- only the folders.

Comment: My other variation of this control, uses 'BeforeExpand' and 'AfterExpand' to populate, however I wanted a way that they are all loaded in memory on load.  the IO is what is causing this to go clunky, but aside from giving up -- there doesn't appear to be a solution in sight.  I find this difficult to accept, that this problem has no solution to achieve the end goal as outlined, and that I should just switch back to the `BeforeLoad`.  It really doesn't feel like drives perform as well as they claim, when I could index folders faster on windows 95.

Comment: My experience is other than yours. Enumerating this many folders doesn't take that long. Adding that many nodes to a tree view lead to quadratic scaling. Remember that your real code is not adding all nodes at the top level. It's easy to make this work. Do the same as every single shell program. Enumerate lazily. Only enumerate when you need to. Only populate the tree when you need to. Do you think Explorer enumerates the entire volume before showing you anything?

Comment: I understand, but I was looking to get away from the whole non-searchable trees that are missing the "find in tree" ability (something that died some time ago).  It's painfully sad that I can get a list of all folders with "dir /s /ad"   faster than with any of this .net crap. What I would like ideally, is a form of cluster list to just pull from the file system table a list of all folders. Also, would like to know where the info is hidden for folders that have icons assigned so I can toss that call and just grab that all at once as well.

Comment: David, just following up.  I have reverted back to the traditional OnExpand get nodes method, but it's performance still sucks from a UI perspective. See here for elaboration on the issue > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807079/adding-folder-structure-to-treeview-taking-hours

Comment: Found a way to populate the treeview with all folders in just a few seconds. Posting the solution here.  I still have a delay when using the `OnBeforeExpand` to get the icons for folders even when doing a check to see if `desktop.ini` exists first (600 MB / s SSD so really shouldn't be an issue).  Please look over my solution after I post it and see if you can optimize the images for folders that have different images.

Comment: Sorry, the other post is actually :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819229/treeview-expand-still-taking-a-while-when-minimizing-to-just-next-level-folders  .   I believe that my solution here elaborates much more on the slow down, as well as all steps taken to improve performance. Currently, my custom treeview has two modes. One that depends on onexpand to get the folders, and one that populates all folders on start from the Journal.  Getting the custom icons is really the slow down now.

Answer (score -1):

I'm willing to bet that the code is not the reason, it can be one of two things:

1. your hard drive is a mess , for that you can try fragmentation methods.
2. (what also happend to me) your folders are not indexed by windows (indexing - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexing_Service) to fix it you need to go to the main folder you are working on and ask windows to index the folder and all of its sub folders (somewhere on the folder box), this proccess will take about a day, but after that your programm should work fine (and fast).

Comment: The indexing service slows your system down in general for a slightly faster search performance as it needs to be updated every time a file or folder is changed / created / deleted / etc. And of course there is the performance issues when it becomes too large,   and also while it is running your system may take a huge performance dive.

Comment: @Samuel Jackson op was asked what can be wrong with his code, i answer that , ther's nothing in my answer that even implies thst indexing is  not slowing down the pc, and when one have a lot  of work on big file systems, for him indexing will be a good idea..

Comment: Just clarifying, I didn't down-vote you either.  It is a viable answer, just is unlikely to resolve anything in this case.  Also on windows 10 where it's impossible to just use normally with indexing off. Windows Vista forward, the file system has been atrocious.